# R reshape dataset

Tags: r

I am trying to reshape to wide a dataset using R, this is the code, I would like to have `df2` but I am struggling a bit.

```
value <- seq(1,20,1)
country <- c("AT","AT","AT","AT",
             "BE","BE","BE","BE",
             "CY","CY","CY", "CY",
             "DE","DE","DE","DE",
             "EE", "EE","EE","EE")

df <- data.frame(country, value)
df

#    country value
# 1       AT     1
# 2       AT     2
# 3       AT     3
# 4       AT     4
# 5       BE     5
# 6       BE     6
# 7       BE     7
# 8       BE     8
# 9       CY     9
# 10      CY    10
# 11      CY    11
# 12      CY    12
# 13      DE    13
# 14      DE    14
# 15      DE    15
# 16      DE    16
# 17      EE    17
# 18      EE    18
# 19      EE    19
# 20      EE    20
```

```
#new dataset 
AT <- seq(1,4,1)
BE <- seq(5,8,1)
# etc

df2 <- data.frame(AT, BE)
df2

#   AT BE
# 1  1  5
# 2  2  6
# 3  3  7
# 4  4  8
```

Any help?

Comment: This base solution works on the given data set : `with(df, data.frame(split(value, country)))
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `tidyverse` (`dplyr` and `tidyr`)

```
df %>% group_by(country) %>% 
  mutate(row=row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = country,values_from=value)
# A tibble: 4 x 6
    row    AT    BE    CY    DE    EE
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     5     9    13    17
2     2     2     6    10    14    18
3     3     3     7    11    15    19
4     4     4     8    12    16    20
```

Answer (score 2):

We can reshape to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(country)  %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = country, values_from = value)
# A tibble: 4 x 6
#     rn    AT    BE    CY    DE    EE
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1     5     9    13    17
#2     2     2     6    10    14    18
#3     3     3     7    11    15    19
#4     4     4     8    12    16    20
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
out <- unstack(df, value ~ country)
str(out)
#'data.frame':  4 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ AT: num  1 2 3 4
# $ BE: num  5 6 7 8
# $ CY: num  9 10 11 12
# $ DE: num  13 14 15 16
# $ EE: num  17 18 19 20
```

Comment: The latter returns a list, so would need `data.frame(...)`, right?

Comment: @Lyngbakr  No, it is returning data.frame based on the OP's example

Comment: @Lyngbakr But, it is not a general solution because it fails when the group lengths differ

Comment: Right, like my solution (which I put in the comments since it's not a general solution, too), but it's a neat use of unstack.